# How to join multiple column in same table?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 table "student" and "picklist". 
 picklist - used it
   as common table for listing like state, country, city.

**Here is student class:**

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Long accountId;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="country",referencedColumnName = "name"),
        @JoinColumn(name="accountId",referencedColumnName = "accountId")}
    )
    PickList country;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="state",referencedColumnName = "name"),
        @JoinColumn(name="accountId",referencedColumnName = "accountId")}
    )
    PickList state;
}
```

**Here is picklist table:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "picklist", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"accountId", "name"})
})
public class PickList {
    @Id
    long id;

    long accountId;
    String name;
}
```

error --
 `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: column: accountid (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Comment: may my question is duplicate but not find relevant answer

Comment: What is `accountId` used for? Is it unique for either of the tables?

Comment: it is not unique, it is simple column that can be repeatable but accountId and name are UniqueConstraint in picklist table

Comment: Please try to explain better what you are trying to achieve: `picklist` seems like an unnecessary table, being that it holds only a string column, and having a one-to-one relationship with `student`

Comment: wanted to join two non unique column but they are UniqueConstraint

Comment: Your whole design is bad, IMHO. Put countries in a country table, and cities in a City table. Une a ManyToOne and not a OneToOne, since many students share the same country/city. And put a countryId in the Student table, rather than an accountId in the country table. There's no reason to have 400 times the same "France" country, just because 400 students are in France. Having an accountId in entities is also a smell. It should most probably be a ManyToOne to the Account entity.

Comment: Accepted it is bad, but i've condition to do that, is their any alternative to solve the issue on existing design

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear: you have a repeated column in the mapping. That means that you mapped the same database column twice.

Try to do like this 
 @JoinColumn(name="accountId",referencedColumnName = "accountId",
            insertable = false, updatable = false)